# When to use dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to use dispatch when a form is submitted, but it gives me an error saying it's undefined. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I was wondering if someone could spot the error?

Also, I was looking at other peoples code and sometimes they use dispatch and sometimes they just use this.props, which is a better and what is the difference?

```
  submitRenter(e){
    e.preventDefault()
      dispatch(addUser());
  }



  render() {



  return (
    <form>
      <label>
      <input type="text"/>
      </label>

      <button onClick={this.submitRenter} type="submit">Sumbit</button>

    </form>


      )
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators({
      addUser
    }, dispatch)
  };
}


export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(RegisterRenter);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not supply a `mapDispatchToProps` function, then `connect` will use its default behavior and give the component `this.props.dispatch`.  If you *do* supply a `mapDispatch` function, then it's up to you what it returns, and you would need to manually include `dispatch` in that return value.

The point of "binding" action creators is so that you can use them without having to explicitly use the `dispatch()` function.  This is especially useful if you are passing the action creators as props to children that are not connected to Redux.

I personally recommend always binding action creators, and even more than that, using the object shorthand syntax that `connect` supports for `mapDispatch`.  As an example:

```
import {addUser} from "./userActions";

const actions = {
    addUser
};

class RegisterRenter {
    submitRenter(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.addUser();
    }

    // rendering, etc
}

export default connect(mapState, actions)(RegisterRenter);
```

For more info, see the [Redux FAQ entry on "why don't I have `props.dispatch`?"](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ReactRedux.html#react-props-dispatch), and my blog post [Idiomatic Redux: Why use action creators?](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2016/10/idiomatic-redux-why-use-action-creators/).